# Twitter Bootstrap navbar-fixed-bottom custom height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I was using twitter bootstrap for interest. And these days I was trying to make custom navbar. I want to display some information on bottom navbar making it as navbar-fixed-bottom. But I can't customize it's height. The default height is not enough for me.

If anyone has faced this problem and has solution, please, share. Thank you.

Comment: I just made top and bottom navbars. Maybe it has some hacks with CSS. I am not good with CSS at all. Please, check out this fiddle to imagine what I need. http://jsfiddle.net/muminoff/2XZzt/

Comment: Works fine for me. I just added several `li`s and the height increased accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianHeine how did you increase height? Are you using navbar-fixed-bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way... You can customize your Twitter Bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Just change @navbarHeight.

But this will change navbar-fixed-top's height too...

---

EDIT: The website has changed, the new URL to customize Bootstrap is http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do this, Bootstrap _is_ a framework itself after all.

Comment: So how can I customize the height of a navbar-fixed-bottom ?

Answer (score 2):

The navbar should match the size of the content (as long as the content isn't outside the document flow). You will need to increase the padding of the body so that the content doesn't disappear behind the bottom navbar though.
If you're using the responsive bootstrap add the following rule to your css and replace the ?? with the height of your bottom navbar:

```
@media (min-width: 980px){
    body {
        padding-bottom: ??px;
    }
}
```

For non-responsive layouts, declare it without the media query:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: ??px;
}
```