# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**How to set up a custom height (for example `40px` instead of `50px`) for a Bootstrap `navbar-fixed-top` with CSS code ?**

I tried :

```
.navbar {
   height: 40px;
   min-height: 40px;
}
```

but then the text elements are not vertically centered in the `navbar`.

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xg8swcwc/embedded/result/

*Note : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576866/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-bottom-custom-height) question gives its answer with http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, which needs recompiling a CSS with LESS, which is not what is asked here.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, and you can't change the default height of the navbar, you need to change the padding of the links contained at the navbar.

```
 .navbar-nav > li > a{ padding: 0px 15px }
```

The ´line-height´ of your navbar-brand is `20px`. So, if you want to be centered vertically, you need to give the half of this value to `padding-top`.

So:

```
.navbar-brand{ padding-top: 10px; }
```

Comment: it works for me with `.navbar-nav > li > a{ padding: 10px 10px }` except `navbar-brand` which is still not vertically centered... I tried `#navbar-brand { padding: 10px 10px }`  unsuccesfully...

Comment: please, share a fiddle to understand better your problem

Comment: Thanks @cor, but this is what you get with your answer : http://jsfiddle.net/xg8swcwc/1/embedded/result/
The links are not centered. Could you update the jsfiddle with your answer, so it will be easier to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

increasing or decreasing the menu items top and bottom padding's will change the height of nav bard

```
 .navbar-nav>li>a { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
 .navbar-brand { padding: 10px 15px; }
```

According to the height of the logo you can add separate paddings for `.navbar-brand` class

Comment: You have exactly given my same answer

Comment: @Feroza, if you try on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xg8swcwc/embedded/result/, it does not work. There are no `.brand` elements, and direct editing of `#navbar-brand`'s padding did not work... Maybe it is overriden by something else ?

Comment: do following:

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the padding appropriately.

Here's what I did for a site I made before I learnt LESS:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
}
```

You might want to use margin-bottom as well, and might want to change the values, but you get the idea.

Comment: doesn't work for the brandname, etc., see the JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xg8swcwc/embedded/result/

Comment: yeah @Basj I dint need to make changes to the brand name in the previous site. Anyway, check the update and let me know if it works. I've added `.navbar-brand` as well, and it works for me.